# SQL query display customers who only made 1 deposit and 1 only

Tags: sql

I have a quiet big database with few tables, I am trying to run a Query that displays list of customers that made 1 deposit only no more no less. So i am joint two tables on is customers other deposits.

customer table:

id, firstName, LastName, Email, Tel etc.....

Deposits table:

id, customerId, amount, confirmTime etc.....

The SQL query....

```
select
customer.id as 'Customer ID',
(select count(deposits.customerId) from deposits
where customer.id=deposits.customerId) as 'No. of Deposits',

deposits.amount as 'Deposit Amount',
deposits.confirmTime as 'Confirmation TIme'

from customer

left join deposits on customer.id=deposits.customerid

group by customer.id
```

This query returns a nice list of all the customers with the number of deposits the amount and the date, the problem is that the query brings all number of deposits I want the query to show only customers where no. of Deposits  = 1

But I am having problems with this can't think of a right path to achieve this.

Comment: Could you add in a having clause??  Such as having depositcount = 1 ??

Comment: Nope because the deposit table do not keep track of number of deposits this hast to be done manually

Comment: But in your query you have no of deposits fetched right?? At the end of group by add having alias no of deposits = 1 . Tht is what i am saying.

Answer (score 1):

you can make all query as sub-query and add alias to its column. I'm writing here,:

```
    select tab.ID as 'Customer ID',tab.count as  'No. of Deposits',
    tab.dmt as 'Deposit Amount', tab.ct as 'Confirmation TIme' from 

    (select customer.id as ID,(select count(deposits.customerId) from deposits where 
    customer.id=deposits.customerId) as count, 
    deposits.amount as dmt,deposits.confirmTime 
    as ct from customer left join deposits on customer.id=deposits.customerid group by 
     customer.id)as tab where tab.count=1;
```

if it dosn't help you then make me aware i'll tell you another way.